# python bluetooth- showing error

Tags: python, bluetooth

```
import bluetooth
a=discover_devices()
if '24:0A:64:XX:XX:XX' in a:
    print "xyz is here"
else:
    print "xyz just went"
```

Devices were being discovered, so when I tried to access one of it to prompt whenever the device turned bt on or off, an error showed.
that discover_devices not found.
What to do? Plz help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You imported just the module; call the `discover_devices()` function with:

```
import bluetooth

a = bluetooth.discover_devices()
```

or import the `discover_devices` name into your module:

```
from bluetooth import discover_devices

a = discover_devices()
```